# Parsing AJAX response in callback

Tags: ajax, coffeescript

I need to access a piece of data from some HTML response in an AJAX callback.

In my Coffeescript, I want to access the completion-id data attribute. When I do the following:

```
  $('.mark-completed')
    .bind "ajax:success", (event, data) ->
        console.log data
        console.log $(data)
```

I get this in the console for data:

```
<li class="learning_item_completion" data-completion-id="162" data-user-id="2" id="learning_item_completion_162">
  <div class="item-icon">
    <img alt="Thumb_alex_headshot_green_200x200" class="circular" height="60" src="/uploads/user/picture/2/thumb_alex_headshot_green_200x200.png" width="60" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
```

And this for $(data):

```
[li#learning_item_completion_162.learning_item_completion, jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", size: function…]
  0: li#learning_item_completion_162.learning_item_completion
  accessKey: ""
  attributes: NamedNodeMap
  0: class
  1: data-completion-id
    ...
    nodeValue: "162"
    value: "162"
    ...
```

What's the right way to access completion-id?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this :

```
$('.mark-completed')
.bind "ajax:success", (event, data) ->
    cid = $(data).find('.learning_item_completion').data('completion-id')
    console.log cid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html"
}).done(function( html ) {
  $("#results").append(html);
  console.log(html);
//etc.
});
```